# $sce.trustAsHtml does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is something what I am trying to do

`$sce.trustAsHtml('<span ng-class="getIconColor('+ myColor +')">')`

which in my HTML code just prints

`<span ng-class="red">`

But I am expecting `ng-class` attribute to be evaluated before `$sce` returns it. Somewhat like this for my code to work

`<span ng-class="red" class="red">`

How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing ng-click when rendered via $sce.trustAsHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787478/accessing-ng-click-when-rendered-via-sce-trustashtml)

Comment: Why don't you use `$sce.trustAsHtml('<span class="getIconColor('+ myColor +')">')` directly?

Comment: Yeah. That is one work around I figured out. But there were couple of other directives also, like tooltips and I cannot use this method in all cases. I was kinda looking for a more generalized solution.

Comment: Then you can use the custom directive to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a compilation issue, $sce service doesn't work out of the box when you render dynamic content that needs compilation.
you can resolve this by creating your own directive that force a compile.

```
app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
            ele.html(html);
            $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
          });
        }
      };
    })

    $scope.trustedContent = function(){
      return $sce.trustAsHtml('<span ng-class="getIconColor('+ myColor +')">');
    }

<div ng-bind-html="trustedContent()" dynamic> </div>
```

[Rendering directives within $sce.trustAsHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623118/rendering-directives-within-sce-trustashtml)

http://plnkr.co/edit/3CewDscih8diAo4mMSwJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1:-**

In This case, angularjs doesn't compile. Angulajs does not understand about new directive is added and he has execute it. To run case you need to compile your HTML.So Angularjs will understand that and it will give your expected output.

To achieve this you need to create directive, which will do compilation of HTML code.

**Solution2:-**

Instead of this you can directly use `$sce.trustAsHtml('<span class="getIconColor('+ myColor +')">');`