# AngularJS ng-bind-html won't accept input tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've added the code below and it now trusts styles and other tags but still won't accept input tags

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function(string) {
return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
};
```

Comment: `<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml('<input />')"></div>` works, can you show your string or can you test if you are calling that function with console.log() inside of it?

Comment: you can try `ngSanitize` see docs 
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing ng-click when rendered via $sce.trustAsHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787478/accessing-ng-click-when-rendered-via-sce-trustashtml)