# Issue with ng-click event not firing for HTML rendered from SQL Server database

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I render a button saved from SQL Server database. View source for the button looks like the following -

```
<button id="btn" class="mainBtn" ng-click="OpenBtn('btn')" >Do something</button>
```

This button is part of a MainDiv which looks like following -

```
<div id="MainDIV"  ng-bind-html="MainDIVHTML">
```

I assign MainDIVHTML value as follows -

```
 $scope.MainDIVHTML= $sce.trustAsHtml(entity.MainDIVHTML);
```

Where entity.MainDIVHTML is the saved HTML from database.

mainBtn is inside the entity.MainDIVHTML

The saved HTML and the page where I am using saved HTML share the Angular.js controller.

I am not able to execute - ng-click="OpenBtn('btn')" event.

The markup (HTML) is shown correctly though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing ng-click when rendered via $sce.trustAsHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787478/accessing-ng-click-when-rendered-via-sce-trustashtml)

Comment: Yes. That worked good for me. Thanks for the suggestion.